# How to make Windows 7 save new files on secondary desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, desktop-icons

I have two monitors and when I save file on a Desktop, it saves on a primary destop. I need to tell system to arrange new files/icons starting with my secondary desktop. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fences" allows you to organize icons into their own little areas. It might be worth a look: http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/

Comment: Very clever and useful app. That what Windows needs by default!

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a few options and only one is arguably practical:

1. Fill your entire primary screen with dummy files
2. Set your primary monitor to the monitor where you want the files saved

You can use a tool like https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/ and or http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/ to help manage things.